# Microsoft Graph : Unable to Update BusinessPhone Value using User.ReadWrite Scope

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

i'm trying to update the value for "BusinessPhone" using the scope "User.ReadWrite" but i'm receiving the error message " Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".
However i'm able to update MobilePhone value.
I'm using Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario , seems User.ReadWrite permission not enough to update BusinessPhone property . You could add `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` permission which works after testing :

[image]

`Directory.AccessAsUser.All` need admin consent , you could login with your admin account and click `Grant Permissions` button as shown in above screenshot .

After that , use your authentication process and get the token , check whether `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope exists in `scp` claim of access token , you could use [online tool](http://jwt.calebb.net/) to decode token . If exists , try again to update BusinessPhone property with that token  .

Please let me know if it helps .

Comment: Noted, will try that.
Thank you :)

Comment: waiting for feedback :)

Comment: This is by design (currently) and per docs here under the remarks section: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions - and only administrators can change this property currently.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @NanYu-MSFT , i'm now about to use Microsoft Graph to access MS Azure by having the Directory.AccessAsUser.All feature being granted access by the admin.

Thank you :)