# Unable to patch businessPhones of Azure AD user, Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am writing a backend application to update user in Azure AD by calling Microsoft Graph. The application is granted with permissions `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `User.ReadWrite.all`.

When I send patch request to update `businessPhones` of a specific user, successful response code `204` is returned if the businessPhones parameter is an empty collection, i.e. `{"businessPhones":[]}` .

In case the parameter is not empty, e.g. `{"businessPhones":["+86 (321) 456789"]}`, response code `403` is returned with the message "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation".

I have tried to patch for another user, there is no problems with both empty and non-empty businessPhones parameter.

I have found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692544/microsoft-graph-unable-to-update-businessphone-value-using-user-readwrite-scop) but `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is a delegated permission, which is not applicable to my application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check whether the value of businessPhones  is the same to current businessPhones of the  specific user you want to update  ?

Comment: Before I send the patch request, businessPhones of the user is blank. I sent a non-empty businessPhones and 403 is returned.

Comment: I find that if I patch the businessPhones of an user who is global or limited administrator, 403 and "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" would be returned. But I still can patch other properties such as userPrincipalName successfully. If I patch the businessPhones of a general user, there is no problems.

Comment: As of 24th Aug 2017, the situation is resolved after I reported to and followed-up by Microsoft support. The application permission `Directory.ReadWrite.All` can now update the `businessPhones` of an admin.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this Johnny.  We'll go and investigate this.  In general, with delegated permissions, the authorization is based on an intersection of the permissions that the app has been granted **and** the permissions (based on user role) that the signed-in user has. This is described here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#delegated-permissions-application-permissions-and-effective-permissions.

What is the role of the user that is signed-in?  If they are a global admin, they should be able to change any other user's info.  If they are a limited admin (like User Account Admin), they can only change user profile info of regular users (otherwise this would be an elevation of privilege.  Regular users are allowed to change only their own `photo` and `mobilePhone` number.

**UPDATED BASED ON COMMENT**: If the app is using application permissions, then most properties should be updateable by the app.  However, the behavior you are seeing is weird.  We'll need to investigate - and I'll come back to the thread.  This could be a bug.

**UPDATE 8/26**:  This was indeed a bug. The fix has now been deployed.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dan. However my application is a background service to synchronize my user repository to Azure AD periodically. No signed-in users thus no delegated permissions. 
The situation is that my application 
1. can update `businessPhones` of a general user
2. can update `userPrincipalName` of general user as well as global and limited admin
3. but cannot update `businessPhones` of a global / limited admin

Comment: Updated the original answer.  Thanks for clarifying.